# NSdictionary returns error when 1 returns

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Everything works when i get more then 1 objects back but when its only 1 it reacts weird, i can't find the solution for it.

First i set everything in an array:

```
NSArray *array = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"objecten"] objectForKey:@"object"];
if (array == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Expected 'results' array");
    return;
}
```

then i use a for loop on a dictionary

```
for (NSDictionary *resultDict in array) {

    SearchResult *searchResult;


NSString *wrapperType = [resultDict objectForKey:@"type"];    

 if ([wrapperType isEqualToString:@"rent"]) 
 {
        searchResult = [self parseHuur:resultDict];

 }

        if (searchResult != nil) {
            [searchResults addObject:searchResult];
        }}
```

So when results get back more then 1 everything works great, but when just one gets back i get:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e52c30
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e52c30'
```

it points to this line:

```
NSString *wrapperType = [resultDict objectForKey:@"type"];
```

I really don't get it...
i check the results of the api in the browser with the same link and it really returns 1 object, but when i log the resultDict (NSlog it) i get only one answer: id instead of the whole object with all parameters (i don't know if this is the right name for it)

how can that be ?

Comment: So when you are getting only one back, is it dictionary or string? Have you printed the array and checked it?

Comment: @ACB i checked it, its an array i logged it with kindofclass and it fires true statement... i don't get it

Comment: I meant the object, is it dictionary or string which is inside array as a single element. Have you tried printing the objectAtIndex:0 of the array?

Comment: @ACB if i NSlog at objecAtIndex: 0 i get same error (unrecognized selector etc) so how can i know what kind of value it is..

Comment: Try printing, [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"objecten"] , if that also crashes, print [dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"]. One of those returns a string and not a dictionary. Check if that is the format you are expecting.

Comment: @ACB  
if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"DICTIONARY");
i tried the first one too..
its a dictionary..

Comment: What did [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"objecten"]  return?

Comment: Based on our discussion, array is not always an array and it could be a dictionary. So I have added it as an answer, which should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, `array` is not always an array as you have mentioned. It could be an array or dictionary. So try this,

```
id someObject = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"objecten"] objectForKey:@"object"]; //naming it as someObject since it is not always an array

if (someObject == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Expected 'results' array");
    return;
}

if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { //Just add this
    someObject = [NSArray arrayWithObject:someObject];
} 

NSArray *array = (NSArray *)someObject;//type cast to an array now

for (NSDictionary *resultDict in array) {

   SearchResult *searchResult;
   NSString *wrapperType = [resultDict objectForKey:@"type"];    

   if ([wrapperType isEqualToString:@"rent"]) 
   {
        searchResult = [self parseHuur:resultDict];
   }
   if (searchResult != nil) {
        [searchResults addObject:searchResult];
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, didn't lose any result!

Answer (score 2):

Some of your results aren't full NSDictionaries but rather just NSStrings.  You can check for this:

```
for (id result in array) {
   if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
      NSDictionary *resultDict = (NSDictionary *)result;
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried it and now it checks every result if its a nsdictionary class, its very very slow but eventually it works but now when it only returns one result it shows = nothing found, instead of the result...

Answer (score 1):

When you use the fast enumeration for a NSDictionary, the iterating variable is from the set of keys in the dictionary not the values.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html

Answer (score 0):

The resultDict isn't an NSDictionary hence you can't invoke objectForKey: on this object.

A better solution would be to treat resultDict as [id type](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) in the for loop, and check its class type for NSDictionary before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]
```

So it's calling the `objectForKey:` method on an `NSString`. It seems that the API you're using for getting the objects follows a common idiom: it uses duck-typing/polimorphism (to use these nice OO-related words) and it returns either an *array* of objects if it has more than results, or a single object (and **not** an array of one element) when it has only one result. So, you have to use reflection (OMG, even more OO terminology!) to inspect whether the returned object is actually an array - either

```
id result = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"];
id value;
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    value = [[result object objectForKey:@"objecten"] objectForKey:@"object"];
} else {
    value = result;
}
```

or

```
id value;
if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    value = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Result"] result object objectForKey:@"objecten"] objectForKey:@"object"];
} else {
    value = dictionary;
}
```

Try both, whichever works should be fine.

Comment: i understand what you are saying (lol terminology) but i can't get it to work...wait i will edit this post with the log

Comment: oke this is the problem: i used NSlog to see where it goes, wether the app returns a error or not it uses the True statement. so the same error comes back...